# Check date format in conditional split transformation in ssis

Tags: ssis

I am having flat file which contain bad date like [02/02/0200].I want export data into sql table.I am using Condition split or derived column  transformation for date column.

I want that correct date goes to main table and errors rows go to error table.

Could you please let me know what expression i have to used for date column .

Thanks,
Jeetesh Garg

Answer (score 0):

When you convert your date [02/02/0200] it's gonna be 200 Year 02 Month 02 Day.
So you need to eliminate nonsenses dates. This gonna eliminate dates which are lower than  2000 Years.

```
(DT_DATE)([YourDate]) > (DT_DATE)(2000 - 01 - 01)
```

OK so new derived column statement (bccPostDate  - data type is "unicode string" ) :

```
((DT_I4)(SUBSTRING(bccPostDate,1,2))) > 12 || ((DT_I4)(SUBSTRING(bccPostDate,4,2))) > 31 || ((DT_I4)(SUBSTRING(bccPostDate,7,4))) < 1900 ? "" : bccPostDate
```

IS working I have tried with Years and this statement returning column with "Unicode string" data type.

Comment: Thanks......                                                                  I Have passed below expression in Derived column nd it is working           YEAR((dt_date)bccPostDate) < 1900 || MONTH((dt_date)bccPostDate) > 12 || DAY((dt_date)bccPostDate) > 31 ? " " : bccPostDate

Comment: Updated Answer, I take that yours date is this format mm/dd/yyyy if your date format is dd/mm/yyyy you need to change 12 to 31 and 31 to 12 :)